# Asking good questions about rudimentary things

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, closed-questions

Today I asked a question about C# coding that, in all likelihood, seemed too simple to interest the experienced coders who patrol the boards. It was promptly closed.

The question did not seem foolish to me. I had spent nearly two hours trying to understand the matter that I was asking about. I had looked up numerous posts, on both the Microsoft site and yours, that related to my topic BEFORE I posted my question. However, try as I might, **I couldn't make head or tail of the posts** that supposedly related to my topic. That's why I came looking for help.

I'm a self-taught programmer and use a lot of work-around code for problems I encounter. However, while I don't want to boast, I've created dozens of programs that have been used in educational contexts at schools where I've taught. So, while I might be unconventional in my approach, I create workable code and serviceable programs.

To have my question 'closed' in a peremptory fashion with no opportunity to discuss why it was offensive to others, well, I find the matter puzzling and quite insulting. To have that closure followed up with an email saying the question 'was not well received by the community' when only **four** people had thus far looked at the question, seems -- not to be unkind -- high-handed and ludicrous.

If the question I was asking was so rudimentary then why not take two seconds to answer it directly, instead of referring me to tangentially related questions that (as far as I can see) don't address what I was looking for? Certainly they don't do so in a direct way. Perhaps they **do** answer the question and if someone had just taken the time to show me **how they do** that would have been useful and courteous.

You have a great site which has helped me many times. No doubt it is tedious to answer the same question many times, but a bit of patience rather than slamming the door in an abrupt fashion, would facilitate communication instead of shutting it down.

Comment: @Zoe I was actually okay with that lead-in header...

Comment: Still feels like noise. /shrug

Comment: *"To have that closure followed up with an email saying the question 'was not well received by the community' when only four people had thus far..."* - The email is simply a notification of closure in case you missed it on site, nothing more

Comment: Why are you deleting elements of my post? There was nothing inappropriate in what I wrote.

Comment: You have a signature in the question itself, and so it wasn't needed.  Don't take it personal.

Comment: Fair enough. I guess I'm taking it personally because I feel ill-used at the moment.

Comment: While I don't entirely agree with the duplicate chosen, I agree with the sentiment the comment holds. The first result with the search text they provided answers your question (now linked in my comment on your question)

Comment: What have you researched about how the site works to justify your claims & complaints?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, Philipxy. Where would I research that? Nick, if you see how it answers my question, than are you willing to have a private discussion with me about it? I will go and look at your comment.

Comment: @W.C.Bastedo I'm busy sorry, but I think it's pretty clear, you may have to look at both the top 2 answers.

Comment: [help], SO/SE search (poor), googling with site:meta.stackoverflow.com & with site:meta.stackexchange.com. (Also, googling advanced googling.) PS See [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) to learn to use @x to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter x re a comment.

Comment: It is a "if you need to know then you're doing it wrong" kind of question.  The hierarchy is a tree, not an array, tree elements don't have an index.  We don't know why you need to know, but as usual somebody else did not explain it either so I linked to their post.

Comment: Nick, thanks. I was guilty of not reading that whole post earlier. The exact answer I wanted was there.

Comment: If you don't understand a presentation, post a question quoting it & asking about where you are 1st stuck. But if it isn't an authoritative & reviewed presentation, like official documentation or a textbook, and is poor, the resulting question may be unanswerably unclear, and people could also reasonably consider you to not have reasonably researched--in a more authoritative place--that is coherent. This includes not understanding how a duplicate is a duplicate, edit your post to say why you don't think the duplicate is one, or comment on the duplicate, or post a question re understanding it.

Comment: So you.... Had the time to come in and rant about the fact you were pointed to the *wrong* duplicate, a 'tangentally related question'.... Before you actually read all the posts on that link? Isn't **that** an overreaction

Answer (score 7):

Right, so I'm going to address this in the sense that your question was closed as a duplicate, and you don't believe that the dupe answers your question or you don't know how it answers your question.

To be honest, closing a question as a dupe means that **we keep related information together**.  We don't want to have the same question asked twenty different ways available in five-hundred different places, and for that, we use duplicate closure to help assist us.

It's perfectly *fair* to believe that your question wasn't answered by the dupe; if you feel like hanging out, please post a question in regards to your *specific* question and ask why this question was a dupe, here on Meta.  Some C# experts that lurk around here will be happy to point out why it was, or overturn the decision.

It's unreasonable, however, to have an expectation that we're here to hand-hold you through the process of problem solving.  We cannot assume anything about your level of expertise; if you ask us a technical question, you're going to get an answer that is not beyond our expectation for you to understand on your own.

I'm sorry that you had an inconvenience there.  Hopefully you'll not think of us as rude; we're just trying to keep the number of duplicate questions down.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. If the same sort of effort had been put into my original question we wouldn't be having this discussion. I couldn't post a follow up because the site closed down my ability to ask questions. Something about possibly being permanently barred from asking questions, which is entirely strange because all of earlier posts created useful discussions and were amicably resolved. I wasn't asking anyone to hold my hand, just to hold their fire.

Comment: Well, *that's* definitely not due to just one question being asked.  You may have other issues going on.

Comment: Makoto, would you please elaborate? What do you mean 'other issues'? I've asked -- I think -- four questions in the past. I imagine you can see them. None of them created acrimony. I've never flamed anyone here or anywhere.

Comment: @W.C.Bastedo Have you deleted any? They count too

Comment: Questions? No, I sometimes edit posts, but I've never deleted a question. Nick, I'm not a rude person. I always try to be courteous even when, as has been the case today, I'm peeved.

Comment: @W.C.Bastedo I never said you were courteous or rude, there's nothing even rude about editing questions. However you may be forgetful as I'd be very surprised if you got banned from the 5 questions alone that you have.

Comment: @W.C.Bastedo:  [Have a read of this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583/1079354).

Comment: Okay, any how, thanks for letting me vent. I'll take another stab at asking my programming question once the site allows me to do so again. I feel like I'm walking on eggshells, though, because I don't know how I offended people.

Comment: Oh, okay, Makoto. Got it. Maybe they see me as a help vampire. Sigh, could be. It is true that I've never gone looking to help other people with their programming difficulties, but I make my living helping students with their difficulties so doing so in my spare time doesn't appeal to me. Besides, I feel insecure about my own programming methods. Thanks for taking the time, Nick and Makoto.

Comment: @W.C.Bastedo Chances are you did not offend anyone. Downvotes are not reserved for offensive content, it's all about quality, and the quality standards here are high. It might help to follow a tag for a while and try to answer some questions (I'd start by just reading though), since then you'll learn what makes questions high-quality and easy to investigate/answer rather fast and get a sense of commonly asked duplicates too. Duplicates are not meant to shut the door but direct you to continuously-maintained high-quality answers.